# How to dynamically create a generic lambda implementation by type?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-8, predicate

For example, i have class

```
public class Human {

  private String name;

  ...
}
```

and i want to implement something like this:

(1)

```
List<Human> humans =  initHumans();
Equals<Human> humanEquals = new Equals<>();
Predicate<Human> filter = humanEquals.filter("name", "John");
List<Human> filteredHumans = humans
    .stream()
    .filter(filter)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Equals:

```
public class Equals<T> extends AbstractPredicate<T> {

  public java.util.function.Predicate<T> filter(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
    ....
  }  
}
```

is it posible implement filter method to provide the (1) behavior?

I want to return a `Predicate` like this:

```
Predicate<Human> predicate = human -> human.getName().equals("John");
```

similarly should work for other classes:

```
Predicate<Car> filter = humanEquals.filter("color", "red");
//like this:
Predicate<Car> predicate= human -> human.getColor().equals("red");
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use reflection to get the correct getter by name and then you are good to go.

Comment: What's so bad about `human -> human.getName().equals("John");`? That way you can have the compiler check if the attribute you're trying to access actually exists too.

Comment: I don't think reflection is the solution here. Generally, mixing lambdas and method references with reflection indicates a bad design, or a problem more serious than accessing a getter by name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this might be achieved by reflection:

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> filter(Class<T> clazz, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
    // 1
    return (T instance) -> {
        try {
            final Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);

            return fieldValue.equals(field.get(instance));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // 2
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

- I made a method `static` because I have no idea what the `AbstractPredicate` is and why you need to create an instance of a utility class.
- I am getting the value from a field directly without using a getter - what naming convention should we adhere? (it might be improved)

The use is:

```
final Predicate<Human> filter = Equals.filter(Human.class, "name", "John");

System.out.println(filter.test(new Human("John")));     // true
System.out.println(filter.test(new Human("Andrew")));   // false
```

There are still a few questions we need to think of - validating parameters (1), handling exceptions (2).

---

Another option can be using a `Function<T, E>` to provide a reference to a getter:

```
public static <T, E> Predicate<T> filter(Function<T, E> supplier, E value) {
    return (T instance) -> supplier.apply(instance).equals(value);
}
```

An example of use:

```
final Predicate<Human> predicate = Equals.filter(Human::getName, "John");

System.out.println(predicate.test(new Human("John")));    // true
System.out.println(predicate.test(new Human("Andrew")));  // false
```

Comment: The question does provide code indicating the presence of public get-methods in the Human class.

Comment: @VGR, it becomes a bit complicated, what getter name should I look up?

Comment: I guess if the question is taken literally, wanting to refer to a property as a String, there is no other way.  But, there is a bit of an XY problem here:  I suspect Wi-Al would be satisfied with something like `Equals.filter(Human::getName, "John")`.